# C / C++ code communicates with a remote web service on server (tomcat)

Tags: java, c++, web-services, http-post, tomcat

I have C++ HTTP code on the client side which will communicate with a remote web service on the server side.
The server is Tomcat Apache server which is configured on port 8080.
The webservice which I have to access through my C++ http code is at:

```
http://somehostname:8080/some_path/some_api
```

Is this possible?

*1st confusion:* I know that HTTP POST requests are sent on port 80 and here I have port 8080.

*2nd confusion:* The server is Tomcat Apache and the server code(webservice) is in **java**. This means that I have to access that java code through my C++ HTTP POST method. Is it possible to communicate C++ HTTP POST method to JAVA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what i know that HTTP request(POST) is sent on port 80 and here i have
>   port 8080

An application can use any available/free port. By convention certain ports are used by specific applications. E.g. usually HTTP servers run on port 80 but they can also run on 8080 or any other port.

> the server is tomcat server and the server code(webservice) is in java
>   that means the i have to access that java code through my c++ HTTP
>   POST method is it possible to communicate c++ HTTP POST method to JAVA
>   ??

Yes it is possible.
You are essentially sending an HTTP message that the receiving side i.e. the Java application can "understand" it since it will be formed according to the HTTP standard (an HTTP message has a specific format).
All in all an HTTP message is plain text.

You should note though that in general there are many pitfalls when you try to communicate a C++ application with a Java application as there are subtle differences e.g. Java's lack of unsigned primitives compared to C++ etc

Comment: Thanks to all with your valuable suggestion. Now my confusion is clear and i could start my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

1. Just configure the c++ client with a url endpoint as per your example.
2. Yes a c++ client can communicate with a Java server using HTTP. HTTP POST is not java or c++ specific.

Comment: Additionally, on top of the HTTP layer, you may want to consider a serialisation format such as json or one of the xml ones, but this will depend on the libraries available to you. This should move you closer to being able to exchange structured types, rather than effectively raw strings.